# Spring: configure a static field singleton instance

Tags: java, spring, cxf, wss4j

There is CXF's PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor that creates a singleton instance:

```
public static final PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor INSTANCE 
    = new PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor();
```

Having no Spring skills I'm struggling with how to set its acestor's (AbstractWSS4JInterceptor) properties map via Spring's bean definitions in a cxf.xml file. Basically I want to configure WSS-related properties like "signaturePropFile" in cxf.xml.

Can someone show how to set the property map of PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.INSTANCE? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a singleton bean:

```
<bean id="interceptor" class="whatever.your.package.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor" scope="singleton"/>
```

And then inject it wherever I need it

```
<bean id="anotherBean" ...>
  <property name="interceptor" ref="interceptor"/>
</bean>
```

This other bean would have a normal PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor property like this:

```
private PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor interceptor;

public PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor getInterceptor() {
  return interceptor;
}

public void setPolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor interceptor) {
  this.interceptor = interceptor;
}
```

And you would get the same as declaring it static, expressed in Spring terms.  It's up to you which way you prefer, just remember that doing this the Spring way you have your interceptor inside your IoC container, and thus you can instrument it if necessary, etc.

Comment: The bean declaration would create another instance of PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor, right? I think that does not work, because WSSecurityInterceptorProvider uses the INSTANCE to add it to CXF's interceptor chain like this: `this.getOutInterceptors().add(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.INSTANCE);`

Comment: Damn sorry, I had not realized your interceptor is part of a library and thus you don't maintain that code, my bad completely, very sorry.  I had not understood your question at all.

Answer (score 0):

The "action"-based WS-Security properties such as "signaturePropFile" do not work with the WS-SecurityPolicy based interceptors in CXF. CXF has separate configuration tags that you can just pass as JAX-WS properties when using WS-SecurityPolicy, and so you don't need to access any properties of the INSTANCE class. See here for more information:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

Colm.